# SQL - Select between current week number and three weeks behind

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, range, week-number

I'm not that good, when it comes to SQL. I'm trying to get data from the last three weeks. I can get the current week number, but really don't know how to subtract it so that it goes three weeks back and takes all data from that period.

This is my current code. I can make it work with a fixed number (42 in this example), but that's not what I want.

[image]

And this is what the output should be:

[image]

Comment: And what happens when `fldweenum` is 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, [avoid pictures of code...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584).

That said, if you're using SQL Server, I believe the function you're looking for is [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). See if this does what you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblData
WHERE fldWeekNum BETWEEN DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())-3 AND DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE())
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments below, let's try subtracting 3 weeks from the current date, then getting the `DATEPART` for `WEEK` from that date. This depends on how `fldWeekNum` is calculated, so it may need some additional tweaking based on that.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblData
WHERE fldWeekNum 
  BETWEEN 
    DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(WEEK, -3, GETDATE())) 
    AND 
    DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Will this work for the first twenty days in January? I suspect it may have a problem

Comment: Yeah. I bet you’re right, @CaiusJard. I missed that, but then the week field is all that’s shown in the question, and that’ll be insufficient for spanning years.

Comment: Edited my answer based on @CaiusJard's comment.